# How to differentiate or identify if a wifi connection is a tethered network or real broadband network?

Tags: wifi, telecommunication, tethering, broadband

Due to work traveling we have to put up with a location with quite "unstable" internet connection.

The property owner has set the charges including his own "wifi" facility providing to us.

Because the network is quite slow and unstable, we are not sure of it is a real broadband network or rather tethered from "his mobile" - you bet things like this can happen...

So how to identify the connection?

Comment: You think it could be a device like this:https://www.business.vodafone.com/site/bus/public/enuk/support/10_productsupport/wi_fi_devices/r201/05_summary/p_summary.jsp ?

Comment: What's the SSID?  By the way, if you aren't looking for a programmatic solution, this probably belongs on SuperUser, you do know that?

Comment: @SList we just want to find out and jutify this network is a fraud. So there's a possibility to negotiate on charges n apply for our own proper broadband. I will update you with SSID if can find.

Comment: One thing we found out the security type and speed... guess what... it goes below 1MBPS... shame shame in 2014!

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to tell if the connection goes through a tethered cell phone connection or a land (fixed) broadband connection, one way to try is to run a trace route. Once you know the path of your hops getting to the Internet, with little research and correlation you might just find out.